# Simple Objective-C Memory Question - releasing a property, can't reallocate and init

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using this fork of [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/DigitalDJ/AudioStreamer) to stream audio.

In a view controller I have an AudioStreamer as a property:
`@property (nonatomic, retain) AudioStreamer *streamer`

When the view controller loads I start a stream like this:

`self.streamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:preset.url]];`

And to stop the stream, release it, and start a new stream I'm doing this:

```
[streamer stop];
[streamer release];
self.streamer = nil;
self.streamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:preset.url]];
```

This doesn't work because in the initWithURL: method, there's a check to see `if (self != nil)` and that check fails.

Would anyone be able to clarify why this isn't working?

Thanks.

EDIT: It was actually some issues with my project that was causing weird issues. However, I marked an answer as correct because it had some good memory tips that also helped.

Comment: can you show us the code of the initWithURL method?

Comment: What symptoms lead you to believe that the problem is with the `initWithURL:` call? There's nothing at all unusual about that method, and `AudioStreamer`'s super is `NSObject`, so it's pretty unlikely that `[super init]` is failing.

Comment: I had a short glance at the AudioStreamer class, if the initializer is the same in your fork then I actually don't know why it is failing, the class simply inherits from NSObject and the initWithURL isn't doing anything fancy at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overretaining the streamer instance by setting it with the dot syntax and using alloc.

The synthesized setter will retain it once and alloc the second time, you should add an autorelease:

```
self.streamer = [[[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:preset.url]] autorelease];
```

This line:

```
self.streamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:preset.url]];
```

Will automatically release the previously assigned instance for you. So you don't have to call

```
[streamer release];
self.streamer = nil;
```

before it.

However you should do

```
[streamer release];
```

in your dealloc method.

Comment: +1, good catch. Didn't notice he was over-retaining (in addition to incorrect releasing).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're double-releasing `streamer` without intending to.

```
[streamer release];     // Releases the ivar, but doesn't set it to nil.
self.streamer = nil;    // This is a property access, which releases the old
                        // value (again) before setting to nil.
```

And your assignment in the final line is leaking a reference (you're allocing, and then assigning to a `retain` property).

You're sort of mixing access metaphors. If you have the property, then use it exclusively:

```
[self.streamer stop];
self.streamer = [[[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:preset.url]] autorelease];
```

---

All that said, a failed `self != nil` check isn't necessarily explained by this, but it might be, depending on what AudioStreamer is doing for its internal object management.